# Baking Normal Map not working Anvil Tutorial

Tags: normals, texture-baking, normal-map

I'm following Blender Guru's anvil tutorial on baking normal maps and its not working. I don't know what really any of the settings mean and there is a weird oval thing on the anvil; I have no idea why there would be an oval there as its not on the high poly anvil. I've messed with the Extrusion and Max Ray Distance settings, but I can't get the oval to go away without getting rid of all the other details. I don't know what the settings mean and I've just been randomly changing them.

File: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14uU1SJeo4o0JB-2PauhOKiJ0ftxP5-VM/view?usp=drive_link

Screenshot of Normal map:

[image]

Screenshot of oval on anvil with normal map:

[image]

My settings for Bake are default (i think) except:

Bake Type: Normal
Selected to Active
Extrusion: 0.503 m
Max Ray Distance: 0 m

Screenshot of Bake settings:

[image]

---

I sort of fixed it by adding a cage. I don't know if this is possible without a cage. I added the google drive to the blend file.

Comment: I cannot help with your baking problem, but if you don't know what part that oval is, why not check the UV map, select the parts there and see to which they correspond on your mesh? To me it looks like it's a very small part with the UV faces scaled quite large.

Comment: Please pack your image and share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Your link asks for an authorization, we can't download the file